# ¿Cómo concatenar un espacio vacío?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando con C# y necesito concatenar un espacio en el texto de `Descripción`.

Lo que hace el método es lo siguiente: al mostrarse el formulario búsqueda, sin hacer click en el cuadro de descripción, se puede hacer las pulsaciones en el teclado y voy digitando lo que deseo buscar (como `CAMISETA`):

```
private void frmBusqueda_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyCode >= Keys.A & e.KeyCode <= Keys.Z) | (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 & e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9))
        {
            var nTecla = e.KeyCode;
            if (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 & e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9)
                nTecla = e.KeyCode - 48;
            else
            {
                this.txtDescripcion.Text = this.txtDescripcion.Text.Trim() + nTecla;
                this.txtDescripcion.SelectionStart = this.txtDescripcion.Text.Trim().Length;
            }
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal)
            this.txtDescripcion.Text = this.txtDescripcion.Text.Trim() + ".";

        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            this.txtDescripcion.Text = this.txtDescripcion.Text + " ";

        if ((e.KeyData == Keys.Back) & (this.txtDescripcion.Text.Trim().Length) > 0)
        {
            this.txtDescripcion.Text = this.txtDescripcion.Text.Trim().Substring(0, this.txtDescripcion.Text.Trim().Length - 1);
            this.txtDescripcion.SelectionStart = this.txtDescripcion.Text.Trim().Length;
        }
    }
```

Ejemplo: escribo `CAMISETA PAT PRIMO`, donde necesito poner los espacios.

Lo que ese código hace es convertir lo que recién ingresé en `CAMISETAPATPRIMO` (sin espacios).

¿Por qué estoy eliminando los espacios?

Comment: Hola Pedro. La pregunta no se entiende muy bien. ¿Puedes describir el funcionamiento del método `frmBusqueda_KeyUp` y cual parte del código no funciona como esperas? Gracias.

Comment: @sstan, Ya agregue la información que me faltaba.

Comment: @PedroÁvila la captura de pantalla luce como un winform hecho en WPF.

Comment: @Mauricio es Windows Form, estoy usando una librería que se llama DevComponents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sentencia siguiente que te concatena el espacio:

```
if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
    this.txtDescripcion.Text = this.txtDescripcion.Text + " ";
```

... sin duda funciona correctamente.

El problema es cuando luego entrás los siguientes caracteres, siempre le haces un `Trim()` al contenido del textbox antes concatenar el siguiente caracter, como lo haces aquí por ejemplo:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal)
    this.txtDescripcion.Text = this.txtDescripcion.Text.Trim() + ".";
```

Ese `Trim()` quita cualquier espacio al final antes de agregarle el punto.

Para resolver tu problema, debes modificar el código para no hacer trims a cada vez que concatenas un caracter.

Comment: Funciono el problemita, ahora es que cuando digito números no los pone en la descripción.

Comment: Eso es algo diferente. Es porque tu `if-else` no está estructurado correctamente.  Si el teclado es un dígito, entra en el `if` y salta el `else`. Si quitas el `else` funcionará. Pero poniéndole breakpoints al código, todos estos problemitas se resuelven fácilmente.